# Rails Dynamically return today's date at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For demonstration purposes: say I am including in the module `TodayDynamicDate` into the model `Foo` below:

```
# app/models/concerns/today_dynamic_date.rb
module TodayDynamicDate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def todays_date
    Date.today
  end
end

#app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  include TodayDynamicDate
end
```

I am wondering if using that mixed in method of `#todays_date` will work how I want it to.

I want the method `#todays_date` to dynamically return the date that the method was run.   I do not want it to return the static date that the rails server was booted up.

**Example:**

Say I boot up the server today, `Friday, July 1st, 2016`.  Here is what I expect the method to return today:

```
Foo.new.todays_date
  => Fri, 01, Jul 2016
```

The server continues running and it is now `Tuesday, July 5th, 2016`.  That same method is called in the app and here is what I expect it to return:

```
# dynamically returning the date that the method was called
Foo.new.todays_date
  => Tues, 05, July 2016
```

I want to ensure that it *will not* return this:

```
# returning a static date
Foo.new.todays_date
  => Fri, 01, Jul 2016
```

**Question:** Will my implementation return a *dynamic* date?  If it will not return a dynamic date: how would I do that with that mixed-in method `todays_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is yes.  Each call to `Date.today` will return current date.

`todays_date` is not a class (what you are referring as static) variable, its a method.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So are you saying that if `todays_date` was a class method, then it would return a static date?

Comment: A method, either class or instance method, will always return the today's date and not some old cached value.  If you were using a class variable, i.e. if you did `@@today = todays_date`, and used `@@today` in your code, then you will be in trouble